# Azure Extra Large vs A5 machines

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I tried looking up in SO and in in general googled around, but could not find much.

--** EDIT - Intention of the question not to ask where should I host my IIS, but to understand the differences between two editions of Azure VM and in general is IIS suitable to be run in which edition of VM (A5 or XL) **

(I) What is the main difference between "Extra Large and A5 instances"? I can see that there is a difference in CPU cores and also a mention that you must use A5 for "memory" intensive operations. I understand memory intensive as a word, but why would I host my IIS in 2 cores (A5) when I have 8 cores (Extra Large) as a choice (with the same 14 GB RAM)?

(II) Will I benefit from moving my IIS from Extra Large to A5? Is IIS memory intensive or CPU intensive?

Thanks in advance for any pointers or explanation.

Cheers
Vj

Comment: I suspect you will not be able to get a definitive answer without benchmarking your application on both cloud stacks under controlled conditions.

Comment: @Simon, Thanks. I was more so wanting to understand what is the main difference between Extra Large instances and A5 instances in Azure. The subsequent question was IIS is advisable to be run in XL mode or A5 mode.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about comparing virtual cloud machines.

Comment: @Daniel, there seems to be no clear comparison that exists that explains the reasons why two virtual machine editions exist which differ in CPU cores but nothing else and gives a vague explanation of "memory intensive" (from Microsoft blogs). So I wanted to understand real life experiences of pros and cons of each. I was not trying to compare Azure to AWS. Hope that explains

Comment: @VJVRR but this question still isn't about programming.

Comment: @Daniel, Is there a better place that you can help me with where I can post this question? That will be appreciated.

Comment: @VJVRR try calling microsoft. i know there azure reps are pretty good.

Comment: @Daniel. I will. Thanks. I am hoping / will wait if somebody takes interest in answering / sharing any of there experiences. Thanks for taking the time to suggest anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's you application that will have more direct influence on the memory and cpu utilization rather than just IIS.

if you know your app is more memory intensive rather than cpu intensive, why would you want to pay more for the extra processing power that you don't get to use?

A4 is almost twice the cost of A5